# Event workflow in SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer

Clearly I need to edit my question.

If I'd like to create a process, a process for registering and handlig some kind of event inside an organisation, where you first register this event, by giving it a title, and some other properties (date, description etc), then this event should be handled in some ways, this will be done in several steps in order to resolve this event. What would be the best way to do this? I'm not looking for an answer in code, just a keyword for what this could be called, or a guide/tutorial, or a link to something similar.

All help is appriciated, if u don't understand my question please tell me, and I will try to elaborate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tagged this SharePoint, I assume you have a SharePoint site set up already. On that site, you want to create a list (either a calendar list or a custom list; try both and see which option has more columns you'll use, then add/remove columns until you're capturing all the data you need). Then you want to create a **workflow** (or workflows) that run on items created in that list. Workflows created in SharePoint Designer can do everything you're asking, from sending automatic emails to changing fields in your items. Googling "SharePoint workflows" will start you down the road to developing your solution.